# Visual Studio Code Inconsistency Running Python File

Tags: visual-studio-code

I couldn't find an answer to this so it might just be how the program works, but I've been working in Visual Studio Code for a while now, in Python, and when I run the program, it doesn't always actually run. There's nothing wrong with the code, if I keep killing the terminal and running the file it'll eventually work, but I was wondering if there's a way to get it to do it the first time consistently.

Comment: What command you exactly run? Did you run `python [your_file].py`?

Comment: `There's nothing wrong with the code`, most of the time there is something wrong in the code if you have inconsistent behavior

Comment: @ArRakin I'm clicking "run python file" in the top right of the program.

Comment: I have always used the launch config and never had any problems, the same with the Interactive Python

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the code runner extension and then using run python file option.
[code runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rEBW.png)
[code runner button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRSzD.png)

Comment: After installing code runner and making sure my buttons match your picture, it doesn't seem to have changed how often visual studio will run my file.